# Modal popup on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have a requirement where in i will click on a button and submit the form but in between want to show a dialog to show some information to the user and post which continue with the submit action is that possible??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is that posible.

U can try a message alert, for example, with [sweetalert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/), [sweetalert2](http://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/) and much more!

Comment: But hows this possible could you please write some steps on how to achieve it.

Comment: I have a button on clcik of which will call a function getdetails() but in between show a user amesaage in modal which but how to continue with the journey without any activity on the modal??

Comment: I personnaly used "Apprise(v2)".js which is kinda complete, you can custom your alerts with input fields, data and so on... Google it ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a confirmation mesasge in the modal dialog then the submit action should be inside the modal dialog itself.

If it is something like:Are you sure you want to submit? then you can use the JavaScript confirm and return the result, ex:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return getDetails();"/>
<Script>
function getDetails()
{
return confirm("Are you sure ....");
}
</script>
```

Comment: But i dont want to do anything on modal dialog just want to show the messge and continue with the operation

Comment: So, why are you showing the message? will it appear and disappear without any user interaction? if so, you can use setTimeout and call another function that will do the actual form submission

Comment: Also how can we show this message only once when he /she clicks on the button and next time will not show the message

Comment: Firs question: how to do submission from the dialog: you can have another function that submit the form and call this function after showing the dialog using setTimeout. or after clicking a button in the dialog

Second question: you can have a hidden field in the page or a cookie and set its value to false, once you showed the message for first time, set its value to true and always check this value before showing the dialog